# How to calculate the power supply values for an non-inverting Op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, non-inverting

I'm trying to figure out the power supply values for a non-inverting Op amp circuit. So far I have: input voltage= .03 mV, Gain=11, and output voltage=330mV.

I know my output voltage cannot exceed my power supply value, but am not sure how to caluclate it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since your maximum input and output voltages are in the neighborhood of 350 mV, they do not affect your supply voltage requirements.

You simply need to follow the minimum supply voltage requirement from the op-amp datasheet. This might be +/- 1.5 V or +/- 15 V (or anywhere in between) depending on which op-amp you have chosen. Only the datasheet for your op-amp can tell you. You might also choose to use a higher supply voltage than the minimum, if it is already conveniently available in your circuit.

Since you are using a non-inverting configuration you might also be able to work with a single supply. Whether this is possible depends on exactly how close you need to bring the output to 0 V, and how much current the op-amp will need to sink with the minimum output voltage. Achieving output very close to 0 V with non-trivial output current (1 mA or more) could require very careful selection of the op-amp.